# Beginner question about representations and Jordan forms

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

I have just started studying representation theory of finite groups in finite dimensional vector spaces. I have question about writing a representation as direct sum of subrepresentations.

Now assume we have a representation $$G\rightarrow GL(V)$$$$p:g\rightarrow p_g$$ and let $V=W_1\oplus W_2...\oplus W_r$ and $W_i$ is $p_g$ invariant for all $i,g$ and $W_i=span\{v_{i1},v_{i2}...,v_{id_i}\}$ ($dim(W_i)=d_i$). If we set this base, $B=\{v_{11},...,v_{1d_1},...,v_{i1}...v_{id_i},...,v_{r1}...,v_{rdr}\}$ for $V$ then the matrix form of $p_g$ becomes a block diagonal matrix, say $A_g=diag\{A_1,A_2,...,A_r\}$ and each $A_i$ is subrepresentation, $A_g=A_1\oplus A_2\oplus ...\oplus A_n$

So my  question is can i do the reverse? I mean if i have a representation $A_g$ -i know i can write it's Jordan form wihch is block diagonal and they are isomorphic representations since they are similar- can i always find or construct such bases as in example to make each subspace $A_g$ invariant?

For example let $A_g=diag\{A_1,...A_r\}$ and $A_1$ is $d_1\times d_1$ matrix, pick $W_1=span\{(1_F,0,...,0),(0,1_F,0,...,0),...(0,0,...,1_F\text{($d_1-th$ entry)},0,...,0)\}$ would not this representation be $W_i$ invariant?
 If so this should mean every finite dimensional representation which is not in form of a jordan block can be written as direct some of subrepresentations where those are the jordan blocks, right?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to be careful here. Note that the shape of those blocks may depend on which element of the group you pick, when you try to do this in reverse.

Comment: but even they differ for each g, isn't the result of $Aw_1$ in the subset $W_1$? @TobiasKildetoft

Comment: Where did the $W_1$ come from hen doing this in reverse? If the Jordan blocks have different sizes, what do you do?

Comment: ok say A is 4x4, $A=diag\{J_1,J_2\}$ and $J_1$ is 2x2 and $J_2$ is 2x2 Then i pick $W_1=span\{(1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0)\}$  $W_2=span\{(0,0,1,0),(0,0,0,1)\}$ for example.

Comment: But that was just one shape. What if the shape for another group element was $3\times 3$ and $1\times 1$?

Comment: if two elements of the group do not commute, there is no "common" Jordan Normal Form for them, so I am not sure how useful it will be.

Comment: oo ok i think i got it now. Of course they don't have to have  same jordan blocks or eigen values . Thank you!

Comment: Fortunately, once you get a bit further, you will see "replacements" for this, most notably Maschke's theorem which does show that the representation is a direct sum, and Schur's lemma which implies that if the group is abelian then the summands are $1$-dimensional.